# Use constants as references for asserting equality of strings in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

We are constantly having an discussion internally whether or not it should be accepted by reviewers that a PHPUnit test asserts for a string value inside a PHP Constant like so:

```
$this->assertSame(Command::FAILURE, $this->commandTester->getStatusCode());
```

Instead, some of our team would like to do it like so:

```
$this->assertSame(0, $this->commandTester->getStatusCode());
```

Their argumentation is that if the constant value is changing due to an update or so, we would not be able to detect it.

My personal feeling is that it does not matter, as we utilize the constant as it is, so we do not care for its literal content. We do only care for the value it possesses, and that it should always be the same (tested + actually returned value).

I do not find any strong indication online to if this is personal preference or best practice.

So, dear developer community, what do you think about this? Should constants in tests be used or avoided?